# Why use dynamic arrays/pointers instead of std::vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, memory

When I first learned C++, I avoided STL because the project I was contributing to didn't use it all (still don't know why).

Here's how we did things instead.

First, we have a `memory` class which houses a template function, which looks like this:

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   create a 1d array
------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

  template <typename TYPE> TYPE *create(TYPE *&array, int n, const char *name)
  {
    bigint nbytes = ((bigint) sizeof(TYPE)) * n;
    array = (TYPE *) smalloc(nbytes, name);
    return array;
  }
```

When making an array in a program, we simply do (e.g. 1D double array of size 10):

```
double *myArray;
memory->create(myArray, 10);
```

When freeing the memory, we call this template function:

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   destroy a 1d array
------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

  template <typename TYPE> void destroy(TYPE *&array)
  {
    sfree(array);
    array = nullptr;
  }
```

Which is used like this:

```
memory->destroy(myArray);
```

What are the pros/cons of making arrays this way, instead of simply doing `std::vector<double> myArray(10)` ?

People often say we should use `std::vector` because it prevents memory leaks... Is that it? Is the only reason because someone might forget to do `memory->destroy(myArray)`?

EDIT: I'm not asking about the benefits of the features/accessory functions that come with `std::vector`, like `push_back` or `sort`. I'm wondering why anyone would choose to use dynamic allocation of pointers over `std::vector`.

Comment: To be clear - are you asking for a list of every feature offered by `std::vector` that isn't offered by a dynamically-allocated C-style array?

Comment: For what it's worth, in any non trivial program, people _will_ forget to free memory. That's why smart pointers and containers are important.

Comment: Best case? This `memory` class was written by someone who had a very weird, specific embedded system use case and didn't know that `std::allocator` was a thing. Worst case? The person who wrote this code was, and I'm using the technical term here, an idiot. This looks like a bootleg C-style `malloc` that forgoes all type safety and sensibility in an effort to eliminate the benefits of C++. If a coworker wrote this, ask them why, and don't take anything less than a perfect answer. If you're a student and an instructor gave you this, then find a better instructor because this is a nightmare.

Comment: @DrewDormann I should clarify that I'm not asking this, I'll edit my OP. They made their own push_back functions for example and put them in the memory class. Then there are separate functions for sorting and other operations used in other parts of the code.

Comment: _"Is the only reason because someone might forget..."_ C++ has exceptions.  That means a memory solution like yours may leak regardless of whether someone forgets to manually free memory.  What you are comparing against `std::vector` strongly resembles what someone might write in C.

Comment: There are a lot of companies that make their own implementations of foundational classes. They've decided their implementations can be better optimized and tailored for their needs, or they decided not to trust the STL implementations from their compiler toolchains, or maybe they had some other reason we could only guess. You really should have asked them

Comment: The code uses 4 star pointers.  Maybe a good exercise is to rewrite it so it is more sane.  Second is that the template will fail miserably if `TYPE` isn't trivially copyable.  Then I doubt the class itself can be copied and assigned without memory leaks and double-free errors.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo it's a very popular simulation software maintained by national labs. I'm wondering if their use of dynamically allocated arrays helps performance or something...

Comment: `std::vector` isn't any slower than a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: `std::vector` *is* a dynamically allocated array. It's just that the compiler provides guarantees about it. Guarantees that your linked code ignores entirely. Paul makes a good point: Four star pointers is a huge red flag. I don't care if the Pope wrote that library: it's a mess, plain and simple. If they really needed to do that level of pointer manipulation, they should've used C or directly written asm instructions. That has never been what C++ was intended to do.

Comment: Not my downvote, by the way. Your question is well-posed, and every issue I take is with the nightmare of a codebase you've linked, not with anything you've said.

Comment: @Thermodynamix I tried to look for a destructor for that class, and didn't even find one.  Definitely that class is not safe to use in a non-trivial program.  So using such a class is basically signing onto something that leaks memory.  If the author intended to use C++, they should have, at the very least, use C++ idioms.  If the class was not meant to be copied, then make the copy constructor and assignment operator disabled.  If the template can only work with POD types, then there should have been a check for them at compile-time, etc.

Comment: Given that your memory solution uses `smalloc`, this code will also have undefined behavior when allocating any type that has a non-trivial constructor.  As I mentioned before, this code resembles C code that was eventually tried out on a C++ compiler.

Comment: @DrewDormann There's also a comment in the code saying not to use it on any nontrivial classes. Though, according to the note, it's to avoid "code bloat", not to avoid undefined behavior. These people had no clue what they were doing.

Comment: I certainly don't have the time to do it, but a good experiment would be to rewrite that code using `std::vector` and compare the sizes of the final executable (after optimizations are enabled).  Then the "code bloat" justification can be proven to be either true or false.  It would be very funny if the `std::vector` code is similar in size, and the author wrote all of that code in that C-style, basically for no reason.

Answer (score 3):

Most commonly, this is because the code predates the existence of STL.  It may even have originally been C code that was migrated to C++ at some point.

With a modern compiler, there is no reason to reimplement STL std library classes.  For any newly written code there are essentially no pros to doing this and plenty of cons.